# How to remove comma at end of extracted value?

Tags: regex

I am having the following String

```
{'Sample': '#it{tq}', 'Yield': 0.011063753491221462, 'Error': 0}
```

and I would like to extract the value from 'Sample', that means '#it{tq}'. I tried that using a regular expression: `'Sample':(\s*.+?\s)`
but its giving me: `'#it{tq}',` including that comma at the end. Does anyone know how to erase the comma at the end?

Comment: It looks like JSON. Why not use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this regular expression should do the job.

**regex:** `'Sample':\s*('[^']*')`

https://regex101.com/r/DL5Ltq/2

Comment: Many thanks. But this would give me 'Sample': '#it{tq}'. I only need '#it{tq}'

Comment: @ChrisS. I've updated the expression.

Answer (score 0):

how about using this:

```
'Sample': '(.*?)',
```

beware that the regex in the accepted answer cannot process the case having single quote escape text inside the capture group like this: {'Sample': '#it'{tq}'}.
If you use (.*?), it greedily process any single character inside two single quote.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained *why* this might work better.